# Is Vishalakshi and Devi Vimala mentioned in any scriptures?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, goddess, shaktism

I know Vishalakshi is a goddess of Kashi and Vimala a goddess of Puri. But, any scriptures mentioned about this goddesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vishalakshi is mentioned in the Varaha Purana, being born from Vaishnavi's (a form of Mata Trikala) anger and darkness, amongst other goddesses also being born.

[image]

Vishalakshi is also mentioned to be the goddess of Kashi in the Matsya Purana (13.26)

[image]

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423751.html) of Kashi Khanda of Skanda Purana, Vishalakshi appeared with Vishwanatha for grant the boon to Kubera.

> 141-142. Thereupon, Lord Viśveśvara himself accompained by Goddess Viśālākṣī manifested with a delighted mind. He glanced in the direction of the lord of Alakā, who was standing motionless like a post directing the mind towards the Liṅga. The Lord said, “I am the bestower of boons. Enough of your penance, O lord of Alakā.”

Now, for Vimala.

From the book *Shodhganga: Iconical representations of Śiva*, Vimala is said to have been born from the Aghora face of Sadashiva:

> Rauravāgama mentions the same theory as the Āgamas like
> Kāmika, Yogaja, Cintya, Kāraṇa, Ajita, Dăpta, Sūkṣma and Sahasra
> are emanated from the Iąāna face of Sadāąiva; Aṃąumān,
> Suprabheda, Kiraṇa, Niąvāsa, Svāyambhuva, Anala and Văra are from
> the face called Tatpuruṣa of Sadāąiva; Raurava, Makuṭa, **Vimala** and
> Candrajñāna are from the Aghora face of Sadāąiva; Bimba, Prodgăta,
> Lalita, Siddha and Santāna are from the Vāmadeva face of Sadāąiva;
> Ąarvokta, Pārameąvara, Kiraṇa and Vātula are sprung from the
> Sadyojāta face of Sadāąiva.

I could not find any Puranic reference though, other than in the Matsya Purana reference image above, where it states "Vimala in Purushottama."